# Persisting state of process post mortem Python

Tags: python, persistence, recovery

Let's say I have the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    j = 0
    while True:
       j = j + 1
       print j
       time.sleep(1)
```

if I Ctrl+C or if I closed the program window in the middle of runtime, is there any way to persist the state of the process before it died? And then recover the process from the exact point that it died? If not in python is there any other language that has this functionality?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#module-pdb  works well.  Windows Idle has a decent post exception stack viewer.

Answer (score -1):

Crtl+C raises [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html). You can put your code inside a try except block and handle the KeyboardInterrupt before exiting.

```
import sys
import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    j = 0
    try:    
        while True:
           j = j + 1
           print(j)
           time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        with open('myprog.dat', 'r') as f:
            f.write('j = {}'.format(j))
        sys.exit("Data saved!")
```

You could also check if the data file exists, and read from the data file to initialize the value of j.

Comment: This saves some data, not the state of the program. You couldn't resume the program where it stopped, for instance.

Comment: you're absolutely right, this is a bad answer to the op's question.